# wtforms' processing of incomplete form data

Tags: python, wtforms

This WTForms 3.0 [FAQ entry](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/faq/#why-does-blank-input-not-go-back-to-the-default-value) states (visit the link for full text)
:

> A key design decision of WTForms was that form data -always- takes
> precedence when there’s a form submission. That is, if a field exists
> on a form, and a form was posted, but that field’s value was missing,
> it will not revert to a default, but instead store an empty value (and
> in some cases cause a validation error.)

However my program seems not to confirm that.

```
import wtforms
from werkzeug.datastructures import MultiDict

class MyForm(wtforms.Form):
    field = wtforms.fields.StringField(default='default')
    other = wtforms.fields.StringField()

form = MyForm()
form.process(formdata=MultiDict({'other': 'user'})) # 'field' missing
print(f"{form.field.data=} {form.other.data=}")
```

There is a form with two fields, but the data for one field is missing. The other field is just for confirming the data was processed.

The program prints:

```
form.field.data='default' form.other.data='user'
```

but I was expecting:

```
form.field.data='' form.other.data='user'
```

Am I misunderstanding something?